# Print echo and return value in bash function

Tags: bash

I want print echo in function and return value. It's not working:

```
function fun1() {
    echo "Start function"
    return "2"
}

echo $(( $(fun1) + 3 ))
```

---

I can only print echo:

```
function fun1() {
    echo "Start function"
}

fun1
```

Or I can only return value:

```
function fun1() {
    echo "2" # returning value by echo
}

echo $(( $(fun1) + 3 ))
```

But I can't do both.

Comment: See similar question in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17336915/return-value-in-a-bash-function/67673545#67673545

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, depending on what you wish, there are several solutions:

1. Print the message to `stderr` and the value you wish to take in `stdout`.

   ```
   function fun1() {
       # Print the message to stderr.
       echo "Start function" >&2

       # Print the "return value" to stdout.
       echo "2"
   }

   # fun1 will print the message to stderr but $(fun1) will evaluate to 2.
   echo $(( $(fun1) + 3 ))
   ```
2. Print the message normally to `stdout` and use the actual return value with `$?`.
   Note that the return value will always be a value from `0`-`255` (Thanks [Gordon Davisson](https://superuser.com/users/7778/gordon-davisson)).

   ```
   function fun1() {
       # Print the message to stdout.
       echo "Start function"

       # Return the value normally.
       return "2"
   }

   # fun1 will print the message and set the variable ? to 2.    
   fun1

   # Use the return value of the last executed command/function with "$?"
   echo $(( $? + 3 ))
   ```
3. Simply use the global variable.

   ```
   # Global return value for function fun1.
   FUN1_RETURN_VALUE=0

   function fun1() {
       # Print the message to stdout.
       echo "Start function"

       # Return the value normally.
       FUN1_RETURN_VALUE=2
   }

   # fun1 will print the message to stdout and set the value of FUN1RETURN_VALUE to 2.
   fun1

   # ${FUN1_RETURN_VALUE} will be replaced by 2.
   echo $(( ${FUN1_RETURN_VALUE} + 3 ))
   ```

Comment: I would not recommend using option #2 -- the return value is a 1-byte integer, which means it'll always be in the range 0 - 255. If you try to return 256, you'll get 0 instead. Try to return -1, and you'll get 255 instead. The return value is really intended to indicate success (zero) vs failure (nonzero), and trying to use it for anything else will lead to confusion.

Answer (score 3):

With additional variable (by "reference"):

```
function fun1() {
    echo "Start function"
    local return=$1
    eval $return="2"
}

fun1 result
echo $(( result + 3 ))
```

Comment: Should be the accept answer.

Comment: Caveats and additional info https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#eval

Answer (score 2):

A *funny* resolution could be tailing the last line of `fun1()` as a returned value:

```
function fun1() {
    echo "Start function"
    echo "return:"
    echo "2"
}

# Create a temporary file
output=$(mktemp)
# Run and redirect the output to console and to file simultaneously
fun1 |& tee $output 
# Get the last line of the file into returnValue
returnValue=$(tail -1 $output)

echo $(( $returnValue + 3 ))
```